# colorbox manual closing - API methods not working

Tags: drupal, colorbox

i am using jQuery *colorbox* plug-in and $.colorbox() method to load a site page in a pop-up window ( basically , a nag screen sort of thing ) . It's working perfect .

what i need now is to make an action/link button(within this modal window) to close this pop-up . i have already tried `parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()`,`$.colorbox.close()`,`$.fn.colorbox.close()` but didn't find any success .

Answer (score 0):

$.fn.colorbox.close() works!
Is there any javascript errors in debug window?